# If i do not choose any picture and click back button, it crashed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

**Error message :**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.keepair.myapplication, PID: 31796
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=66536, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.keepair.myapplication/com.example.keepair.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
```

**CODE :**

```
    mGetImageFromGalleryButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_getgallery);
    mGetImageFromGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        requestPermissions(
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                2000);
                    }
                    else {
                        startGallery();
                    }
                }
            });

    private void startGallery() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        cameraIntent.setType("image/*");
        if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == 1000){
                Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
                try {
                    bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), returnUri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mImageview.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
            }
            returnUri = data.getData();
            Glide.with(this)
                .load(returnUri)
                .override(1280, 1280)
                .centerCrop()
                .crossFade()
                .into(mImageview);
        }
        else { #What is good for this space? }
    }
```

My code is doing that if user click `mGetImageFromGalleryButton` in `GalleryFragment`, user would can go gallery and choose one picture, and then back to `GalleryFragment` with that picture's uri.

**Question :**
If a user click `mGetImageFromGalleryButton` and so go to gallery, but do not choose any picture and click android back button, the `Error message` i said above is happened. So, i think i have to modify if clause on `public void onActivityResult`. If what i think is right, What is good for `else { #What is good for this space? }` Would you help me?

Comment: I think it's Uri returnUri = data.getData(); line which is causing the crash

Comment: @septemberboy7 Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Catch the null data returned when nothing is selected; part of writing good code is handling nulls

Comment: you dont need this ( public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  ..... ) -- you could just set a public static variable, when you visit the gallery set it to (none)  -- should the user choose a pic then set the variable to the uri -- then in the activity (OnResume) just have (if the static vaiable is not = "none" do whatever) -- that will be a lot less code to work with -- https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is null when you do not select any image. That is why it is giving the error. Put a condition around your code if your data is not null.

E.g

```
if(data != null){

   //Proceed with your image crop etc

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
  Uri returnUri = data.getData();
  switch (requestCode)
  {
    case 1000:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && returnUri != null)
    {
        Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
        try 
        {
            bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), returnUri);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mImageview.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
        Glide.with(this)
        .load(returnUri)
        .override(1280, 1280)
        .centerCrop()
        .crossFade().into(mImageview);
    }
    break;

  default:
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    break;
  }
}//onActivityResult
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, Jon Goodwin.

Comment: You have done the mistake again, The exception occurred at data.getData() where data is null. You have to make a check on data

Comment: @Joyal C Joseph no I don't think so, have you spotted something ? I think I only make a secondary reference to returnUri, which is ok (&& returnUri != null) brackets and all/ ;O) Best read the code again !

Comment: No where the data itself is null , check at the crash report.

Comment: Yes I see it, you seem not to ! I made an assignment  Uri returnUri = data.getData();   do you see now ?

Comment: your welcome @H.fate just a bit more detail to finish it off, your may have more than one return code (requestCode) I cut down my standard code for you. Keep some standard code in a static library, or somewhere, so that you can refer to it in the future, no point re-inventing the wheel all the time. ;O)